# Playing a video in VideoView

Tags: java, android

I can't figure out why I'm not able to play a video in my `VideoView`.
All I'm getting for a message is:

[image: Error]

I created an SD card for my emulator as well. Do I need to place my SD card in a particular folder in my SDK? Please comment.

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="videoplayer.oxbir.com.videplayer.ActivityMain">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"/>

<LinearLayout/>
```

Here's the code:

```
package videoplayer.oxbir.com.videplayer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.net.Uri;

public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView btnPause, btnStop, btnPlay;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        //String Buffer = "android.resource://com.gsm_developers.videoview_gsm/"+R.raw.dirin;
        String Buffer = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.dirin;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Buffer);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your `VideoView` with this code:

```
  <VideoView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/videoView"
  android:layout_gravity="center" />
```